# Scan barcodes in Filemaker

Tags: barcode, filemaker

I need to scan barcodes in Filemaker 5.5, but the problem is that Filemaker 5.5 cannot handle the "ENTER" key, as far as I know and someway the barcode reader needs to launch a script on Filemaker. If someone had a solution for this it would be great ! (Even some plugin would be good)

Comment: What do you mean the "ENTER" key? you can run a script-trigger on pressing enter... I suspect knowing the model of your scanner would help since they should have some documentation...

Comment: Can you run a script-trigger in Filemaker when enter is pressed in a field ? If yes I would be happy to know how ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can, see [OnLayoutKeystroke](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/script_trigg.38.10.html#1028792), you can alternatively configure this via menus (in Layout mode)...

Comment: That looks great, but what I forgot to say is that (for this solution) I am still stuck with Filemaker 5.5 - is it also available in 5.5 or is there another solution to manage "ENTER" in 5.5 ?

Comment: I'm afraid I have never used Filemaker <10 (and I'm unsure when this functionality was introduced...), best I can say is have a look in the menus for script-triggers. *Probably someone else here will know better*.

Comment: Yes I found your function in FM10, it looks interesting. But for FM5.5. I still need a solution. Do you have a hint on how to ask ?

Comment: I suggest wait, give the question a few days, perhaps rephrase it to make it clearer it's about Filemaker 5.5 (and perhaps script-trigger alternatives, if you're sure these are the thing you need).

Comment: I recommend updating to Filemaker 12. I also recommend reading http://www.amazon.com/FileMaker-12-Depth-Jesse-Feiler/dp/0789748460 to find out why I recommend updating to Filemaker 12 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, you can achieve the desired action via script triggers in a recent version of FileMaker.

There is no way to trigger a script via the enter key in FileMaker 5.5. Script triggers didn't exist yet.

Going back to my pre FM7 way of thinking, you could make the field, that you are going to scan into, a button. The button triggers your script and the script goes into the field for the user and pauses the script. The enter key would then unpause it.

There are other ways too. Are you capable of writing a plugin? Is it too much trouble to have the user push a button after the scan?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, yes it's too much trouble to have the user press a button (in this case it's no use to scan anymore). But yes, I already wrote plugins and I capable but it was a long time ago, I would be happy if you had hints on how to write one and how to do it in such a case...